# Is MVC5 compatible with SimpleMembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, simplemembership

After attempting to upgrade an mvc4 project to mvc5 (following http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) I am getting the following exception:

```
Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'MvcMembership.TouchUserOnEachVisitFilter'
```

Is MVC5 compatible with SimpleMembershipProvider? What is the simplest solution to getting the project working with MVC5?

Comment: Please always be sure to read the helpful descriptions that pop up when adding tags.  You added a new tag when an existing tag from the list was appropriate instead.  Now I have to spend the next day making sure `mvc5` dies ... *again*.

Comment: MvcMembership is not SimpleMembership.  I don't know what that is, but it's not something that ships with MVC.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This brought to light the root of the problem.  We are using SimpleMembershipProvider but the old MvcMembership that we were using before (and was not properly removed) is causing this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. We were using SimpleMembershipProvider but the old MvcMembership that we were using before (and was not properly removed) was causing this error.